# sql-function to get lines including a certain date

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, date

I have an SQL table with columns like this:

```
Person | Property 1 | Property 2 | ... | BEGIN-DATE | END-DATE
```

I'd like to get all Information that are valid on a certain date.

Is there a special SQL-Function (like `BETWEEN` or `OVERLAPS`) checking if `BEGIN-DATE < DATE < END-DATE`? (Somehow the opposite of `BETWEEN`.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE getdate() between BEGIN-DATE and END-DATE
```

Comment: great! Didn't know it also works like this (maybe I should have tried it before asking *shame*)